# Runtime error for CLang compiled program (Mac) reading double type with std::cin

Tags: c++, c++11, osx-mavericks

I'm pretty new to C++ and working through some examples of the book *"Programming Principles and Practices Using C++"* (2nd Edition). I wrote the following simple Program (in file Main.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {

    double d = 0;
    std::string s = "";

    while (std::cin >> d >> s) {
        std::cout << "--" << d << " " << s << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "FATAL? "<< d << " " << u << "\n";
}
```

Compiling the program (on the command line) with CLang (`Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0 Thread model: posix`):

```
clang++ -o Main -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ Main.cpp
```

works fine without any errors. However, when I run the program it behaves strange. I tested the following input:

```
123m
```

which results in

```
--123 m
```

which is fine (the same holds for entering `123 m`). But, entering the following:

```
123a
```

results in:

```
FATAL? 0 m
```

The same happens for most other characters (e.g. `b`, `c`, ...). Entering `123 a` works fine though (output: `--123 a`).

Using GNU g++ works on the other hand. Further, the problem does not come up on a Linux machine compiling the same program with CLang.

As stated before, I'm new to C++ and this seems to be a Mac OS X specific problem. Is this a bug in the Mac CLang implementation or am I doing something seriously wrong here :(?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it fail with `123f` but succeed with `123g`?

Comment: Yes, it fails for `123f` and succeeds for `123g`.

Comment: By the way, this behaviour only occurs when reading a `double`. When changing the type of `d` in the example above to `int` the program works "flawless".

Comment: So it looks like it thinks the input is hex...

Comment: As the program fails for inputs with suffixes `a` to `f` that answer seems to surface. Sadly, entering `123i` or `123x` also fails.

Comment: How about explicitly adding `>> dec >>` to force it to recognise decimal only?

Comment: Adding `>> std::dec >>` does not make any difference.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds like a huge bug...

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that this is indeed a bug in the `C++11` implementation (or `CLang` implementation?) on OS X. Especially as the same program compiles and runs fine on a Linux machine and on my Mac compiling with GNU `g++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::basic_istream::operator>>` calls `std::num_get::get` to extract the value from input. Until `C++11`, the behaviour of `std::num_get::get` was like that of `scanf` with the [appropriate formatting string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get). `C++11` onwards, `std::num_get::get` ends up calling [`strto*` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof), which have a more flexible matching than the one based on `scanf`. In your example, `123[a-f]` get interpreted as hex. Since all the input has been consumed by `>>d`, the `>>s` part of `while(std::cin >> d >> s)` leads to the parse failing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the documentation. So to get this straight for me: `C++11` parses the input different so that `123[a-fipx]` (please note that the input fails also for the suffixes `[ipx]`) are interpreted differently. Compiling the program with GNU `g++-4.9`, however, produces a correctly running program. Further, `CLang` and GNU `g++` (also `C++11`!) produce working programs on a Linux machine. That still seems to be a bit odd for my taste ;).

Comment: `strtod` is specified as not reading hex digits unless the input specifically started with `0x` or `0X`, so this doesn't seem to explain it unless there is also a compiler/library bug. Also, `scanf("%lf` is specified by referring to `strtod` .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution to the problem in this question asked: [CGAL: How can I successfully compile and link CGAL examples (on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689245/cgal-how-can-i-successfully-compile-and-link-cgal-examples-on-mac-os-x-10-9-ma?rq=1)

Compiling with `clang++` as follows:

`clang++ -o Main -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ Main.cpp`

instead of:

`clang++ -o Main -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ Main.cpp`

solved the problem.

Anyway, as `libc++` should be the preferred library to use with `clang++` (as I just was told offline) I think it's time for a bug report.