# Reading integer into int and string into string with standard input c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  while (true){
  int n;
  string a;
  cin >> n;
  if (cin.eof())
    {break;}
  if (!cin) {
    cin.clear();
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
  }
  cout << n;
  }
}
```

When i input 1 2 +. The output would be 12. but I want it to be 12+. Whats wrong with this code?
it works if i input 1 2 a 5 b 7 but for some reason it doesnt work for +.

Comment: Please provide some input data you want to process and failing scenario.

Comment: didnt i? I said I want to input 1 2 + but the output would always be 12 not 12+ which is what i want.

Comment: Sorry, I some sense yes. Do wanna parse a modified polish notation?

Comment: BTW you should not do `cout << n` in the case that `cin >> n` failed. It's be clearer to put `if ( cin >> n ) cout << n; else if ( cin.eof() ) break; else { cin.clear(); cin >> a; cout << a; }`

Comment: Oh yeah i added the else on cout << n after i posted the question in my code.

Comment: theres another question that i have. Why do i need to Control-D twice to end the program? Should just one Controld-D which is EOF end the program? or is there something wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that `cin >> n` is consuming the `+`, because that could be part of a valid integer (e.g. `+5`); but then the integer input fails because it wasn't followed by a digit.

With stream input it cannot "look ahead", it has to make a decision on a character by character basis. This is why `strtol`, or `std::stoi` etc. are more reliable than reading an int via `operator>>`.

The C++14 text `[facet.num.get.virtuals]/3 stage 2` specifies that the `+` should be consumed by the invalid read; however library implementations often don't exactly follow the standard with respect to reading numbers via `operator>>` because the standard is [defective and changes a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689378/characters-extracted-by-istream-double).  So you may or may not find other compilers behaving differently.

To avoid this situation entirely I'd suggest taking a different approach; e.g. reading a `string` every time, and then making other checks such as `std::stoi` or otherwise to see if that string was an integer.

Answer (score -1):

The plus sign can be parsed via char.

```
  char ch;
  cin >> ch;
```

and you will get the +-sign parsed.

Finally, you want probably get:

```
int a, b
char op;

cin >> a >> b >> op;
```

Afterwards you can reorder your output arbitrarily. E.g, `std::cout << op << " " << a << " "  << b`

Comment: That will fix this particular test-case; but the question implies that it should read a general sequence of integers and strings, not just `1 2 +`.

Answer (score -1):

change line 7 from

```
int n;
```

to

```
char n;
```

would solve the problem

Comment: You mean, read everything as single chars, rather than as integers and strings as the OP wants? How will that help?