# Why is iostream cutting off the first letter in certain words?

Tags: c++, iostream

Note: please read the comments before answering. The problem seems to be compiler specific.

I have a simple program which reads a name and some grades from a file or the console into a struct Student_info, and then prints out some of the data by overloading the << and >> operators. However, the program is cutting off parts of or even entire words and shifting the data. For example, the input

```
Eunice 29 87 42 33 18 13 
Mary 71 24 3 96 70 14 
Carl 61 12 10 44 82 36 
Debbie 25 42 53 63 34 95
```

returns

```
Eunice: 42 33 18 13 
Mary: 3 96 70 14 
rl: 10 44 82 36 
25: 63 34 95
```

suggesting that somehow, the stream has ignored the first two letters of Carl, and then shifted the entire stream left 1 word. I've been trying to debug this for the better part of an hour, but it seems arbitrary. For different names, different words get cut off, with no apparent pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student_info {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output,
                                    const Student_info &S ) { // overloads operator to print name and grades
        output << S.name << ": ";
        for (auto it = S.homework.begin(); it != S.homework.end(); ++it)
            std::cout << *it << ' ';
        return output;
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &input, Student_info &S ) { // overloads operator to read into Student_info object
        input >> S.name >> S.midterm >> S.final;
        double x;
        if (input) {
            S.homework.clear();
            while (input >> x) {
                S.homework.push_back(x);
            }
            input.clear();
        }
        return input;
    }

    std::string name; // student name
    double midterm, final; // student exam scores
    std::vector<double> homework; // student homework total score (mean or median)

};


int main() {
    //std::ifstream myfile ("/Users/.../Documents/C++/example_short.txt");
    Student_info student; // temp object for receiving data from istream
    std::vector<Student_info> student_list; // list of students and their test grades
    while (std::cin >> student) { // or myfile >> student
        student_list.push_back(student);
        student.homework.clear();
    }
    for (auto it = student_list.begin(); it != student_list.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit: added newline character.

As you can see it doesn't work with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XRnauZwhhc8TNkmh), but it does with [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FZV6YE0iK8xKI7yQ)

Comment: Read the whole line into a string with `getline()`, then use a `std::stringstream` to read it into the struct members.

Comment: It runs pretty well on my computer.

Comment: @ArnoldLayne Odd. I'm compiling in XCode 8.3.3, and [this](http://imgur.com/a/bxNvU) is the output.

Comment: I used gcc 4.9.3 to compile it.

Comment: It works for me in Visual Studio 2017, however the output is all on one line since you have no newlines in it.  Works here too: http://ideone.com/aMpO7T But not here using clang: http://rextester.com/XSK69499  Interesting.

Comment: Add a z in front of the names and it works fine. I can't explain Debbie, but `ca` is a number in hex which appears to be why prepending a z fixes it. You can also add any number of a-f in front of the names after the first and it will eat those characters too. http://rextester.com/ZJZS39415

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the data or writing it? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Hey why don't you do one thing, cout student after every cin inside the while loop. Then see results. Is that okay? With gcc it works just fine. Or maybe your file isn't in ansi.

Comment: You might read the comments.  This is an issue with one specific compiler, not broken code.

Comment: I suggest to give a try to this. Shift all your code to gcc but keep the file same. Try reading the same file with gcc

Comment: I don't think anyone is getting the point of the bounty, it's my first one so perhaps I did it wrong. The code works, but not on clang, and that's what I'm curious about. Is there undefined behavior causing this or is clang just weird? There are many ways to read the data differently, but there seems to be nothing wrong with this way other than the clang weirdness.

Comment: @JAustin @RetiredNinja I was thinking the problem is with the way the clang compiler recognize the "\nCa" string as a ´double` but it is not added to the homework list, so I doubt it was really the issue but it may be related with that. The problem can be solved looking for the eol while looking for homework values as in my answer

Comment: @RetiredNinja I can confirm that replacing double types with ints fixes the problem. Now why the clang compiler interprets these characters as doubles is a different question. I think you are correct that it is only affecting names whose first letter can be read as hex digits, but this seems like an odd and fairly serious problem with the compiler if there isn't some deeper reason for it. Thanks for the bounty, by the way. It's an interesting question.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689378/characters-extracted-by-istream-double

Comment: minimum example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZNGvloR9fzs4TzGG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Characters extracted by istream >> double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689378/characters-extracted-by-istream-double)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an inconsistency between implementations of how they implement the standard when it comes to failed floating point formatted input.

`clang` (or more precisely, `libc++`) reads and discards all characters that a valid floating point representation could possibly contain, even if it cannot contain them at this position and the conversion will necessarily fail. These characters include `C` and `A` (both upper and lower case, because they are hexadecimal digits and hexadecimal floating point number notation is actually allowed by the standard). Thus, when trying to read a `double` and the input contains `Carl`, the characters `C` and `A` are read and discarded, even though no floating point number can start with either of these characters.

On the other hand, `gcc` (`libstdc++`) stops reading as soon as it becomes clear that the conversion will fail. Thus, if the input contains `Carl`, the conversion stops at the first character (and it is retained in the stream), because a hexadecimal floating point number cannot start with `C` (it must start with `0X`).

I won't volunteer an opinion about which implementation is formally correct. Whatever it may be, normal code should steer clear of subtle and mysterious corners of the language. If a student record is a line, then the code should read lines. If a student record is defined as "a name and a sequence of numbers that last until the next name", then stop and read [this article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: and now we need an adventurous guy or gal to dive into the standard and come back with a ruling about what the standard says. Nice catch btw.

Comment: @bolov there is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689378/characters-extracted-by-istream-double) that explores this problem and there are some interesting external links.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  The linked question is great!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is while parsing the input with the `end of line` and the `double`.
I found 2 ways to solve it:

1. Read homework until the end of line.

   ```
   friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Student_info &S)
   { // overloads operator to read into Student_info object
     input >> S.name >> S.midterm >> S.final;
     double x;
     if (input)
     {
       S.homework.clear();
       while ((input.peek()!='\n') && input >> x)
       {
           //std::cout << x << "\n";
           S.homework.push_back(x);
       }
       input.clear();
     }

     return input;
   }
   ```
2. Do not parse it as double if you know the inputs would be integers

   ```
   friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &input, Student_info &S)
   { // overloads operator to read into Student_info object
     input >> S.name >> S.midterm >> S.final;
     int x;
     if (input)
     {
       S.homework.clear();
       while (input >> x)
       {
           //std::cout << x << "\n";
           S.homework.push_back(x);
       }
       input.clear();
     }

     return input;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When you know that information for a `Student_Info` object is always in a single line, it is better to use the following strategy.

1. Read a line of text.
2. Construct a `std::istringstream` from the line of text.
3. Extract the data corresponding to a `Student_Info` from the `std::istringstream`.

It just makes the parsing code simpler and less error prone.

```
// overloads operator to read into Student_info object
friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &input, Student_info &S )
{
   std::string line;
   if ( !getline(input, line) )
   {
      // Problem reading a line of text.
      return input;
   }

   std::istringstream str(line);

   str >> S.name >> S.midterm >> S.final;
   S.homework.clear();
   double x;
   while ( str >> x)
   {
      S.homework.push_back(x);
   }
   return input;
}
```

FWIW, I can't duplicate the problem you are seeing. Check out a working version at http://ideone.com/13wHLa.

Comment: I didn't add the bounty, but note that the problem seems to be compiler specific, as the code works when compiled with gcc, but not with clang.